# Number of rows incorrectly retrieved with updateQuery() statement

Tags: mysql

I want to print the number of rows retrieved from an updateQuery() statement in JDBC (mysql database). The code I have till now is this:

```
    int rows=0;
//constructor sets this up like opening connection, etc...
String buildSelectQuery = buildSelectQueryForCode();
            stmt = connection.createStatement();
            rows= stmt.executeUpdate(buildSelectQuery); <---- mismatch
            System.out.println(rows);
```

Where buildSelectQuery is `CREATE VIEW  viewName AS (SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE gen-congruence>1)`. There is a getRows method as well in the class:

```
public String getRows(){
    return Integer.toString(rows);
}
```

Now, this query should ideally pull out over 2000 records and this is done in the view as well (in the database actually) but the getRows (which is being called in the GUI) prints out incorrect number of rows in the view (0) and I have no idea why. Is there another method to setup the result set? Am I doing something wrong? Please help me.

Comment: Why do you think **creating** a view will actually retrieve the rows. Rows are retrieved using a `SELECT` statement.

Comment: Should I create the view first then? I'm sorry, I'm new to JDBC actually ..

Comment: That has nothing to do with JDBC, that is basic SQL knowledge. Maybe you should start with a SQL tutorial before going on with the Java/JDBC programming. E.g. here: http://sqlzoo.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is **creating** a view, not selecting from the view, so no rows are returned. You need to update *rows* when some rows are read.

Comment: How could I do it for views then? Because I don't wanna create concrete tables.. Just temporary ones because this data is going to be dynamic..

Comment: @SharadhaJayaraman: what's wrong with a simple `SELECT` statement?

Comment: If you just want to run the query every time you instantiate the object, get rid of the `CREATE VIEW viewName AS`. Otherwise you need a method to select data from the view and call this method at some point.

Comment: Because I don't want this data to be permanently put into a table.. Just for temporary storage.. Is there a better solution then?

Comment: You haven't put it anywhere at the moment! What do you want to do with your 2000 rows?

Comment: I have to basically filter data out in stages. I have a big table (22000+ rows) which I filter out to get these 2000 rows and then filter it out again to 200 rows (say).. So I wanted 2 temporary tables.. Is there a better solution to do this?

Comment: It depends how you want to filter. It might be possible to do all this with a single SQL query - SQL is designed and optimised for this. I suggest you open a new question which poses your problem of selection. It would be great if you could look at http://sqlfiddle.com and put in some table definitions and test data. Don't forget to tell us which version of SQL you are using.

Comment: Okay, I will put up another question regarding this :) Thanks alot. I am using MySQL 5.2 CE..